# Access 2010 - Runtime mode displays only one form

Tags: ms-access, forms, tabs, runtime, mode

Hey everyone, I am attempting to create a runtime mode version of our Access database by renaming the file extension from .accdb to accdr, according to Microsoft instructions. The problem is that when I open this renamed file, only one of my forms shows up as a tab. Specifically, the form that I set in Options->Current Database->Display Form.

Has anyone run into this before? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I got it. A similar question has been asked in the forums but I must have missed it when I searched. Here is the forum post:

[ms-access: when i change extension to ACCDR forms/tables disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989910/ms-access-when-i-change-extension-to-accdr-forms-tables-disappear)

I haven't confirmed it yet, but it looks like I need to build the navigation controls for accessing the forms, as they do not show up automatically as tabs.